# How to check and replace certain ngFor td text in angular 8

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I would like to know how to find certain td text and replace all of the texts with a new text in angular.

**json**

```
myData = [
   {
     "type": "toyota", 
     "year": "2013",
     "comment": "new"
   },
   {
     "type": "audi", 
     "year": "2013",
     "comment": "new"
   },
   {
     "type": "honda", 
     "year": "2019",
     "comment": "new"
   },
   {
     "type": "ford", 
     "year": "2019",
     "comment": "new"
   }
]
```

**component.html**

```
<div>
 <table >
   <tr *ngFor="list of myData$">
       <td>{{list.type}}</td>
       <td>{{list.year}}</td>
       <td>{{list.comment}}</td> //want to show "old" or " " instead of "new" for all cars with year "2013"
    </tr>
 <table>
</div>
```

Can contains() function works for such in **.ts** file?

Comment: Do you want to display old only for 2013 or all years before that too

Comment: @AdritaSharma He can't show years before 2013 to be 'old' unless year variable is a number.

Comment: @Arcteezy Some logic can be added to handle that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bbmc9t?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

```
<div>
 <table border="1">
   <tr *ngFor="let list of myData">
       <td>{{list.type}}</td>
       <td>{{list.year}}</td>
       <td>{{list.year < 2014 ? 'old' : list.comment}}</td> 
    </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: if I want to display old also for years less tha 2013, how do I go about it?

Comment: Adding that in few minutes

Comment: Check the modified demo

Comment: < or > automatically converts string to number for comparison

Comment: Thanks, I got your point. I will also try and do some stuff in the .ts file to not make this hard coded in the .html.

Comment: Do this `this.modifiedData = this.myData.map(item => ({ ...item, displayComment: Number(item.year) < 2014 ? "old" : item.comment }));`

Comment: Added in the demo as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ternary conditional operator` in `interpolation`:

```
<td>{{list.year <= 2013? "old": list.comment}}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ternary conditional operator `condition? value1 : valu2` as below.

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-us9t2l)

```
<div>
<table>
 <tr *ngFor="list of myData$">
   <td>{{list.type}}</td>
   <td>{{list.year}}</td>
   <td>{{list.year == 2013 ? 'old' : list.comment}}</td> // list.year <= 2013 if you wand to display 'odd' when year<=2013
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For contains scenario, you can check using **includes**

```
{{list.year.includes("2013") ? 'old' : list.comment }}
```